# jQuery set click handler with per-element information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a onclick attribute ontag now that gets set serverside with the `REQUIRED_ID` for when the user clicks on it.
The problem now is that I am trying a more jQuery-like approach where I do set the click handlers on document ready but now I don't have the `REQUIRED_ID` at hand to set it.
I'm wondering what would be the jQuery way of doing this, perhaps setting another tag with the `REQUIRED_ID` and reading it on ready?

NOW:

```
$.ready(
    $('select.attr_satus>option:not(:selected)').each( 
        /* I AM MISSING REQUIRED_ID, WHERE DO I GET THIS VVVVVV*/
        $(this).click(function(){ statusChanged(this,REQUIRED_ID,$(this).val()); }) 
    );
);
```

BEFORE:

```
<select class="attr_status">
<option onClick='statusChanged(this,REQUIRED_ID,"draft");' value='draft'>Draft</option>
<option value='publish' selected="true">Published</option>
</select>
```

`REQUIRED_ID` is an id that changes per row, as I have several of those select tags one after each other.

Comment: It might help to specify what the `REQUIRED_ID` represents, is it a session id, user id, something else? Could it be set/retrieved from a server-side script via ajax?

Comment: I just edited it in, but the id means rowid, like postid, I might have at any moment several rows with random ids, like posts number 3,45 and 67.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your extra information in "data-" attributes:

```
<select class="attr_status">
  <option  data-requiredId='REQUIRED_ID' value='draft'>Draft</option>
```

Then in your event handler you can get it with ".data()":

```
$(this).click(function() {
  statusChanged(this, $(this).data('requiredId'), this.value);
});
```

*edit* — Now "data-" attributes are standardized with HTML5.  Another approach is to use the "class" string, which can contain pretty much anything. What I've done is use a "name:value" notation:

```
<select class="attr_status">
  <option  class='requiredId:REQUIRED_ID' value='draft'>Draft</option>
```

Then in the handler:

```
$(this).click(function() {
  var id = this.className.replace(/^.*\brequiredId:(\S+).*/, '$1');
  statusChanged(this, id, this.value);
});
```

Comment: How standard is adding those data- attributes in HTML? I thought all tags had a fixed set of attributes.

Comment: They're standard with HTML5, and since the whole point of HTML5 is to codify what browsers already do, I would call it safe. If you're using XHTML, and can't change that, you can embed values into the "class" string. I'll extend my answer.